# JQuery Sly Plugin - Mousewheel scroll moves slides 2 at a time instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to get the sly plugin to work properly on a site I'm designing. So, quick background info:

Sly Plugin Examples Page: http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html
Sly Plugin Documentation Page: https://github.com/darsain/sly/tree/master/docs
The page I'm working on: http://turtscher-campos.com/projects/harald-korvas/v3-projects.html

My initialize.js file is using the code/setup for 'CYCLING BY ITEMS' that they had in their demo page (horizontal.js).

The issue: even though scrollBy is set to 1, when I scroll, the code moves two slides per 'mousewheel scroll' instead of 1 by 1, as shown in the CYCLE BY ITEMS demo. I just can't seem to locate the root cause of the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Sotkra

Comment: *the code moves two slides per 'mousewheel scroll' instead of 1 by 1* - cannot reproduce in FF36

Comment: What browsers did you test in?

Comment: Latest versions of Chrome and FF. The thing is, using the same browser, their example works properly for me whereas mine doesn't.

Comment: You'd better to paste related code here or in jsfiddle rather then sugesting inspecting external site. In addition using jsfiddle may help to localize problem by yourself so if your code works in an isolated environment then something else in you app affects it.

Comment: Would be kind of messy to post all that code via js fiddle, and in my opinion, harder for an experienced js user to review when everything is already up there, easily accesible.

Either way, I had someone else run a test for me and they too, could not reproduce the issue. I am left wondering why my mouse fails on my site while it works perfectly on the sample site.

Comment: might sound dumb, but perhaps you should test with a new mouse?

Comment: Yeah, I'll do some extra tests with two other mice to further isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue revolved around my mouse. Tried with three other mice, both on my computer and on a few others. It was only my mouse that yielded the poor result. This doesn't answer why my mouse worked perfectly on the sly horizontal examples page and not on my own but oh well. Lesson learned, check hardware first.

Answer (score 0):

> I had someone else run a test for me and they too, could not reproduce the issue. I am left wondering why my mouse fails on my site while it works perfectly on the sample site

You are free to debug sly's code in [`function scrollHandler(event)`](https://github.com/darsain/sly/blob/master/src/sly.js#L1581) and create an issue or pull request to [sly project](https://github.com/darsain/sly) directly. BTW `function normalizeWheelDelta` looks suspicious. Maybe wrong delta calculates here in your case.

Comment: wheelDelta is needed only for IE8. Either way, I'll continue investigating.